# relationship between config server in mongo sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

there are 3 sharded data servers，each with a replicate set in different places of 3 server 。
what is the relationship between three config server ？
does each config server have full keys or are they have the same data？
how mongos works ，in specific，how mongos  dispatch the request to which config server？

Comment: which version of mongodb ?

Comment: centos6.5   mongodb 3.0.6